# Выравнивание формы по центру (горизонтальное+вертикальное)

Tags: html, css

Есть форма авторизации:

```
<div class = "container">    
<div class = "authorization">
    <table>
        <form action = '/login/' method = 'post'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type = 'text' name = 'login'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type = 'password' name = 'password'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type = 'submit' name = 'authorization' value = 'Авторизаваться'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
*{
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0; 
    }

    .container{
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Подскажите как будет правильнее выровнять форму по вертикали и горизонтали?

container-класс ширины сайта.

Comment: Зачем вы поместили форму в таблицу?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так. Ширина контейнера берётся, как ширина окна браузера. А высота от размера экрана монитора! Выравнивание происходит с помощью `flex`

```css
*{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0; 
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">    
<div class = "authorization">
    <table>
        <form action = '/login/' method = 'post'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type = 'text' name = 'login'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type = 'password' name = 'password'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type = 'submit' name = 'authorization' value = 'Авторизаваться'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```